# Ajax call makes too many times

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have some modals and I want to send some data with ajax, the problem is.. Firstly I'm doing an Ajax call and works nice, then I'm doing next ajax call for another item, and now it's making two ajax call, one for actual item and other for previous. If I'm doing Ajax call for 4 items will do for 5...the actual item, and last 4.

Here is my code

```
$(document).on("click",".addItem", function(){
    var list = $(this).data("list");
    var id_itm = this.id;
    var user_id = '{{req.params.user}}';

    $("#modal").modal('show')

    $('.send-modal').click(function(){
        var types = $("input[name='type[]']").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get();
        $("#type-modal").modal('hide');

        $.ajax({
            type:"post",
            url:"/type/" + list + "/" + user_id,
            data: {id_itm: id_itm, type:types},
            success:function(data){
                   console.log(data);
           }
        })
    });





});
```

Can't find the problem.

Comment: Every time you click addItem ALL send-modal classes will have a new event handler added. Move the event handler outside the click using the same kind of delegation

Comment: And in general...don't nest event listeners inside other event handlers unless you really know what you are doing, are aware of the implications,  and have a good reason to do it

Comment: @mplungjan he probably needs those vars inside the `.add-item` event, either he stores it and move the click for outside that event, or he could add an `off('click').on('click'...`..

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown proper event delegation with good use of data attributes would take care of that